# Pandas : Get top n records based on the sum of every top i record for each group

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a pandas dataframe like this :

```
>>> df

    id    value   
0    1      10
1    1      11
2    1      9
3    2      7
4    2      7
5    2      8
6    3      10
7    3      8
```

I want to get the top two id, based on the sum of their top two values.
So here, I should get this :

```
    id    # value   
0    1    # 11 + 10 = 21
1    3    # 10 + 8 = 18
```

I tried using :

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].nlargest(2).sum()
```

But that returns the sum of all the largest values.

I looked for an answer to my question, but I didn't quite get the proper one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`groupby.nlargest(2)` returns a Series with MultiIndex:

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].nlargest(2)
Out: 
id   
1   1    11
    0    10
2   5     8
    3     7
3   6    10
    7     8
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Here, both the id and the original index appear in the returning Series. Now if you take the sum, it will take the sum of every value in this Series. However, if you apply the sum on level=0 (or on the id part of this MultiIndex), it will only take the sum for each id separately.

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0)
Out: 
id
1    21
2    15
3    18
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Now you have the sum of two largest values for each id. To find the largest two values in this Series you need to call `nlargest` again:

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].nlargest(2).sum(level=0).nlargest(2)
Out: 
id
1    21
3    18
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain what level is doing here?

Comment: how do you find the top 10 in a multi column groupby?  I used result=df_sas.groupby(['Year','Month','fbi_code'])['ArrestInt'].sum().reset_index()
mask=result['ArrestInt']>30
fbi_codes=result[mask]['fbi_code'].unique()  which was cumbersome.  I didn't get my top 10